# Retrieve MongoDB\Client from \MongoDB\Driver\Manager

Tags: php, mongodb

I use `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager` to manage my connections, but I do not use `MongoDB\Client`.
I'm trying to list databases given a connection but the method `listDatabases` is only available via `MongoDB\Client`.

The documentation [states](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBClient/)

> MongoDB\Client is analogous to the driver’s MongoDB\Driver\Manager
> class, which it composes.

How do I list databases from an instance of `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager` ?

Comment: Maybe something with [MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeCommand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php), [MongoDB\Driver\Command](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-command.php), and [listDatabases](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.listDatabases)?

Comment: You can't use adminCommand, but you can use executeCommand on a database, so no, it's not working since I want to list databases.

Comment: If you use `MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeCommand('admin', ...`, it should work, yes?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the driver (i.e. the `ext-mongodb` extension) directly, you don't have the high-level API that the PHP library (which contains `MongoDB\Client`) provides. In this case, you'll have to run the command manually through the manager.

I would recommend using the MongoDB library instead of only using the PHP extension. The extension wraps the C driver and thus only provides a low-level API, while the common drivers API is implemented in the PHP library. This will make working with documents significantly easier.

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP knows that he can't use `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` to list databases in a way familiar to him. You are just restating the problem. Nothing in your answer says HOW TO achieve the GOAL within given constraints. The `Manager` object is likely supplied by godlike powers (DI container, configuration manager, you name it), and the goal is to construct a `Client` instance that connects to the same server, with the same options and privileges. From the POV of the code being written, the `Manager` object is probably the ONLY available pointer towards that information.